# Alternativas do jEnv para Windows

Tags: java, cmd, jdk

Atualmente uso [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/) para trocar entre JDKs em projetos de diferentes clientes, porém essa ferramenta é somente para Linux/Unix/Mac OSX.

Com ela, eu consigo facilmente dentro de cada projeto configurar o uso de JDK 8,11,14 dependendo de cada um. Exemplo:

```
$ jenv local jdk1.8
```

Existe alguma alternativa para Windows? Vou precisar em um novo projeto mas não estou acostumado com Windows.

Algumas conciderações:

- não gostaria de trocar o JAVA_HOME para cada projeto
- em ferramentas como IntelliJ ou Eclipse consigo configurar por projeto, mas quero realizar essa tarefa via *linha de comando*

Comment: Penso que com o subsistema Linux para Windows consegues usar jEnv na mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excelente alternativa é o SDKMAN. Com alguns minutos de leitura voce estará apto a utiliza-lo no windows.

[PAGINA OFICIAL SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/install)

Ferramenta windows que precisa ser instalada antes do SDKMAN: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

SDKMAN funciona apenas em conjunto com o windows linux subsystem (segundo link que te passei), principalmente devido a fragilidade do sistema da microsoft em trabalhar com links simbolicos.